# Probability of passing an exam .

Tags: probability

A student (mohan) appears in two exams . Probability of failing in these exams are (1/4) and (3/20) respectively . We have to find the probability of failing in both exams .

I tried it as

P = (1/4)(3/20)

But my answer is wrong why

In a book the answer is given as

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there $4$ questions on the first exam and $20$ questions on the second exam?

Comment: That formula is only valid if the event of failing the first exam and the event of failing the second exam are independent. Do you have any more information?

Comment: Does $1/4$ mean if you get a score lower than or equal to $1$ then you fail?

Comment: @JackyChong no (1/4) is the chance of failing in an examination

Comment: Then there must be something missing from your question. Otherwise, your answer looks correct.

Comment: I think your question should be "failing at least one exam" not what you wrote "failing both exams".

Comment: The book looks wrong.

Comment: The probability calculated in the book is the complement of the event "Pass test 1 and test 2", but the complement of that event is "Fail at least one test", not "Fail both tests". Either the book is wrong, or you've misunderstood what the original question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your book's solution tells you that the probability of failing *both exams* is one minus the probability of passing both exams.   No, that is the probability of failing in *at least one* exam.

You gave the correct answer for the probability of failing in *both* exams.    Is this the question that was asked?

---

**Remark:** Of course, both answers assume that the events of the student passing each of the exams is independent of the other, contrary to the purpose of testing.

Comment: But what is the wrong method done in the book

Comment: @koolman Nothing was wrong with the method; it was just the answer to a different question.